# what is the efficient way to store html links in a db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails and creating a rails app. 
I'd like to know the efficient way to store html links in a database.

For example, I have a model called "Post" and Post has html links (such as http://example.com) in its content. Those links should be rendered as follows:

```
 POST
 <ul>
   <li><a href="...">html link</a></li>
   <li><a href="...">html link</a></li>
   ...
 </ul>
```

I have three ideas to handle this.

1. Create another model called "Link" (or something like it) to store related links and treat them as a RESTful resource. so, `Post has_many links` in the Post model and render them like `<li><%= link_to "#{post.link.name}", post.link.url %></li>`.
2. Serialise links (with yaml or json) and save them in a newly created "links" column in the posts table, some how extract and render them.
3. Save html links just as it is; `<li><a href="...">html link</a></li>` in a newly created "links" column in the posts table.

The number of these links may either increase or decrease.

So, what do you think is the most efficient way to store links, from the view points of scalability, application performance and maintainability.

Comment: "most efficient way to handle this problem" - what problem?

Comment: I want to render related links to each posts apart from its content and I'd like to add/delete these links later on. The mark up of the list may change in the future.

Comment: Users are entering these links or will they be seed data?

Comment: Authorised users enter these links:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the idea is generally to avoid opinionated questions/answers on SO, I'm going to answer your question anyway.

I would definitely say the first way. Ruby in general is extremely object oriented (true, false, and nil all have objects, no primitives to speak of, etc.). It makes a lot more sense to throw your links into a class. Since it'll be an association, it'll have the benefits of all of the additional methods that you get built-in with rails associations ([see here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)). On top of that, it'll be easily extendable in the future, if you wanted to:

1. Add a follow count to the links
2. Put links on another model in your project
3. Track the ip of the users following the links

and many more possibilities.